# State specific rules and redirects

Tags: angular-ui, angular-ui-router

Is it possible in Angular UI to have a rule which could lead to a redirect from one state to another before resolving and loading a states controller?

Lets say I have the following:

```
$stateProvider.state('questions', {
    url: '/questions/',
    resolve: {
        getAllTheData: questionResolveFunction
    }
}).state('questions.page1', {
    url: 'page1',
    views: {
        'questionView': {
            templateURL: 'template.html',
            controller: 'Page1Ctrl'
        }
    }   
}).state('questions.page2', {
    url: 'page2',
    views: {
        'questionView': {
            templateURL: 'template.html',
            controller: 'Page2Ctrl'
        }
    }
});
```

A user may choose to navigate to page 2. However I do not want them to view page 2 until they have completed page 1. The required information to determine whether or not they can view this page comes from the getAllTheData resolve in the parent state, hence I cannot use a generic $urlRouterProvider.rule() because if someone goes directly to this state from outside the app, it will have no idea about the data when it is first called. This is the outcome I want:

index.html/questions/page2 -> Completed page 1 = true --> go to page 2
index.html/questions/page2 -> Completed page 1 = false -> go to page 1 (don't even attempt to resolve or load page 2)

The example given is a very simplified version of the problem, but should cover everything, let me know if it doesn't. Thanks in advance for the help.